# How do I connect a pin that is not included on the main symbol or any of the gates of an Eagle part?

Tags: eaglecad, routing

In Eagle, I've dealt with a couple of parts that have pads that don't seem to be accessible from the schematic: HTSSOP packages with a thermal pad that should be connected to a ground pin; a battery holder which is a metal can soldered to pads 1 and 3 but Eagle only knows about pad 1.

How do I tell Eagle to put copper between the thermal pad and the ground pin? How do I tell Eagle that the metal can electrically connects pads 1 and 3, even though Eagle must not put any copper between them?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the parts are not defined exactly as you would like them in the Eagle library.  I would make new versions of the parts in the library (I don't suggest directly editing the existing ones) by copying the parts and adding the missing pins.  In the case of the HTSSOP package you will also want to add the thermal pad for the layout.

There are several tutorials on the web re creating and copying parts in the Eagle library, such as [this](http://myhome.spu.edu/bolding/EE4211/EagleTutorial4.htm) one.

Comment: Can't find anything about having one schematic pin that counts as two symbol pins, or perhaps a pad that is more than one polygon? Maybe this feature does not exist in Eagle...

Comment: @joeforker -- just add extra pins to the device, e.g. make thermalpad a pin both in the schematic and the device, and ground it on the schematic.